# Reading Music Path From The Database And Playing It

Tags: android, mysql, database

Basically I Need An Audio Player That Can Read The Path From The Database And Load It 
And How To Read That Song From That Link ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your database has three columns - 
1. id as `id`
2. Song name as `song_name`
3. path to song as `path`

Step 1: Query database to get the path of the song you wish to play

```
Cursor c = yourDBHelper.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"path"}, 
                new String[] {"song_name=?"}, new String[] {"<song_name>"},  
                                             null, null, null);
if(c.moveToFirst()) path = c.getString(0); // This should give the path if the 
                                              query was executed with no errors
```

Step 2: Init MediaPlayer with the above path

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, path);
```

Step 3: Enjoy the music

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

For databsase related help - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html 
For MediaPlayer help - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Also, dint understand what you meant here -

> How To Read That Song From That Link